# Show pop up on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want only the refresh button of the browser and F5 key to show **Don't Reload** pop up and not from any other link on webpage.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure ";
    };
```

Refresh/F5 key shows the below pop up:

[image]

On redirecting the page through link gives below pop up:

[image]

Comment: I am sure this question will be closed soon.  Make sure to add what you have tried atleast.

Comment: Yes, It took time for me to write the whole question along with the findings.

Comment: You can't detect that refresh button on browser clicked or not.. but for `F5` you can check `keyCode`

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be simpler than you'd expect.

We set a keydown event listener on the window object. We then check if the pressed key corresponds with the `keyCode` value of `116` (which stands for the F5 key).

If the F5 key is pressed, we try to reload the page with `window.location.reload();`. The `onbeforeunload` listener will catch this and show you the same warning as with a regular page leave or refresh.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure?";
};

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 116) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
};
```

Comment: Sander: Please see the 2nd screenshot which shows the pop up on click of the link. According to your suggestion it will still show the pop up on click of any link since we are including onbeforeunload event in our code and clicking of the link redirects us to a different page, so it will get reload in case of click of any link.